# CPU utilization in MySQL going very high Sometimes

Tags: mysql, database-administration

How to optimize MySQL CPU utilization is going very high sometimes?

This is my my.ini file

```
slow-query-log=1
long_query_time=10
server-id=1
max_connections=2000
table_open_cache=2000
tmp_table_size=391M
thread_cache_size=10
key_buffer_size=512M
read_buffer_size=64K
read_rnd_buffer_size=256K
innodb_additional_mem_pool_size=32M
innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit=2
innodb_log_buffer_size=256M
innodb_buffer_pool_size=10G
innodb_log_file_size=512M
innodb_thread_concurrency=25
innodb_autoextend_increment=64
innodb_buffer_pool_instances=8
innodb_concurrency_tickets=5000
innodb_old_blocks_time=1000
innodb_open_files=300
innodb_stats_on_metadata=0
innodb_file_per_table=1
innodb_checksum_algorithm=0
back_log=80
flush_time=0
join_buffer_size=256K
max_allowed_packet=256M
max_connect_errors=100
open_files_limit=4161
query_cache_type=1
sort_buffer_size=256K
table_definition_cache=1400
binlog_row_event_max_size=8K
sync_master_info=10000
sync_relay_log=10000
sync_relay_log_info=10000
query_cache_size = 2084M
```

Please Suggest any changes required in this to reduce high cpu utilization?

Comment: You will need to first enable profiling, and figure out the number and type of queries being fired at that time when load goes high. And, then get queries optimized (Also sometimes, application code can be optimized to reuse query results in objects, instead of querying same sql again!)

Comment: Without knowing your server specs it would be guessing game.

Comment: Server Configuration is: 12 core CPU ,2.60 Ghz, 68GB Ram.

Comment: @WilsonHauck , i have pasted GLOBAL status,Global Variables and My.ini Files ,in this is LINK : pastebin.com/t1E5NK6X , and i don't have any MySQL tuner report

Comment: @Ranjanm  Do you have any SSD/NVME or all rotating data storage?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suggestions to consider for your my.ini [mysqld] section (RPS = Rate Per Second)

You may verify these DYNAMIC Global Variables function for your version of MySQL after login as root with:

SET GLOBAL variable_name=variable_value;    (note 128K would be 128*1024   and   391M would be 391*1024*1024 - K & M not allowed for DYNAMIC changes)

Just prior to changing your my.ini each day.   If your request is rejected with 'read_only' message, skip it and let me know, please.

```
# 20180904 1137  from  mysqlservertuning.com
# read_rnd_buffer_size=128K  # from 256K to reduce handler_read_rnd_next RPS
# innodb_io_capacity=1000  # from 200 to allow additional HD RD and WD RPS
# read_buffer_size=128K  # from 64K to reduce handler_read_next RPS
# max_connections=1000  # from 2000 because max_used_connections in 2 days was 244
# thread_cache_size=100  # from 10 to conserve CPU and reduce threads_created of 339 in 2 days
# max_heap_table_size=391M # from 16M to be = tmp_table_size and reduce created_tmp_disk_tables count
# innodb_lru_scan_depth=100  # from 1024 to reduce CPU busy every second see refman
# key_buffer_size=64M  # from 512M because only 11% used today
# innodb_change_buffer_max_size=15  # from 25 percent because less than 1% used 
# innodb_flushing_avg_loops=10  # from 30 to reduce flushing loop delay
```

Each DAY, save your current my.ini in \history with DATED timed filename such as 20180904-1137-my.ini to allow going back to last working  my.ini quickly.

First time, copy this BLOCK (including the leading date and our web site name)to END of your [mysqld] section and ENABLE one change per DAY by removing leading # and spacecharacter, monitor before moving on to next change.

Disable EARLIER same NAMED variable(s) with leading # and space bar, to avoid confusion. In 5 years you will still have history of my.ini changes with approximate dates.

Normally only ONE change per day, monitor before moving to next change. If a change seems detrimental, go back to last working my.ini and let us know, please.

Looking forward to you posting a Review after implementation + 7 days to mysqlservertuning.com, select SHOP, select your item purchased - even if it was FREE, scroll down to Reviews and add yours, please.
Account login is NOT required to post a review.

Comment: Thank you for your kind response with the answer,I will start doing one change per day,i will  start monitoring  the system and keep on updating you on this.

Comment: Thanks For your Analysis on my MySQL server, Now MySQL server's CPU utilization is getting better.  Thanks For Giving  Your  precious Time that you spent with me for Optimizing the Mysql Server from almost 15 days. If any one facing issues with  MySQL please visit 
  [link] (https://mysqlservertuning.com/).it has lot of solutions  to optimize and check your mysql issues.

Comment: @Ranjanm Truly my privilege to assist you.  Please stay in touch.